# Why "ездить на самолёте" but "билет на самолёт"?

Tags: словоупотребление, падежи

With verbs of motion like *ездить* you use *на* + prepositional case for means of transportation and *в* or *на* + accusative for destination, but with *билет* you use accusative for both. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The _destination_ for the ticket is to be used to travel on a plane, that's why _на_ + accusative.

Comment: It is rather `летать на самолёте`.  `Ездить на самолёте` is when the airplane is taxiing (moving on the ground).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun `билет` 'ticket' needs the prepositions `на`/`в` + a noun in the Accusative case, the choice of a preposition depends on what the ticket is used for.

• With kinds of transport `на` + Accusative is used:

> билет на самолёт – airplane ticket
>
> билет на поезд – train ticket

• With entertainment, sport, etc. events `на` + Accusative is used, too:

> билет на концерт – concert ticket
>
> билет на футбольный матч – ticket for a football match

• `в` + Accusative is used with the names of buildings where entertainment events take place, like theater or cinema:

> билет в театр – theater ticket

The use of the Accusative case is due to the fact that those expressions really denote the *destination* where you will go with that ticket.

And naturally, as @user31264 wrote in his comment, with planes you use `летать на самолёте`, not `ездить на самолёте`, because `ездить` means 'to travel on land transport', or 'to travel on a kind of transport', but in this latter case you dont specify the kind of transport. If a European says "Я часто езжу в Нью-Йорк" – "I often go to New York," that would surely imply using either ship or plane.